# Spark Sql z-score calculation with given peer group in Java-8

Tags: java-8, apache-spark-sql

How to calculate z-scores in Spark sql in java-8?

I tried understanding other posts with Window functions, but in my case peer group will be 100.

Comment: what you have tried so far